# change input value by clicking button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the value of input by clicking button. When i click the button the value of input is changed but it hide. My HTML code is -

```
<div id="Tabs">
<ul>
<li id="li_tab1" onclick="tab('tab1')" ><a>Lounge/Family Room</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1">
<p>This is the text for tab 1</p>
<input type="button" value="-" />
<input type="number"id="inputtag" style="width:5%;" value="0"/>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="tab()"/>
</div>
```

And SCRIPT is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tab(tab) {
document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('li_tab1').setAttribute("class", "");
document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("inputtag").value = "1";
}
```

someone tell me why this happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are expecting

```
//HTML
<div id="Tabs">
<ul>
    <li id="li_tab1" onclick="tab('tab1')" ><a>Lounge/Family Room</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab1" style="display:none">
    <p>This is the text for tab 1</p>
    <input type="button" value="-" />
    <input type="number"id="inputtag" style="width:5%;" value="0"/>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="tab()"/>
</div>
</div>


//Script
function tab(tab) {
if(tab)
    document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
else
  {
    document.getElementById('li_tab1').setAttribute("class", "");
    document.getElementById("inputtag").value = (+document.getElementById("inputtag").value) + 1;
  }
}
```

Js fiddle [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/1sja0zgx/3/)

Answer (score 0):

tab() function first line "document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';" it means hide your tab1 div and your textbox inside the this div so how can display your textbox ? if you are display this textbox then remove your first line in tab() function .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tab(tab) {
document.getElementById('li_tab1').setAttribute("class", "");
document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById("inputtag").value = "1";
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is necessory to my tabs.

Comment: okay can you explain me to your requirement in brief? other wise create this example into jsfiddel so i can give you solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You called the function in two ways.
tab('tab1')  and  tab()

You want to show the tab after calling tab('tab1'),
and want to change the input value after calling tab().

In order to use the same function to achieve that, you have to use if to write two cases.

if (!tab) checks if you are calling tab() whereas the else case checks if you are calling tab('tab1').

```js
function tab(tab) {
    if (!tab)
    {
  document.getElementById("inputtag").value++;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('li_tab1').setAttribute("class", "");
        document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
#tab1 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Tabs">
    <ul>
        <li id="li_tab1" onclick="tab('tab1')" ><a>Lounge/Family Room</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab1">
        <p>This is the text for tab 1</p>
        <input type="button" value="-" />
        <input type="number"id="inputtag" style="width:5%;" value='0'/>
        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="tab()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```